# intellij ssh terminal run shell make problem

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, ssh

My legacy spring project on remote server - ubutu, and my local pc is window 11
When my coworkers - mac or window accessed server with iTerm2 or else and run startup.sh, and it was totaly fine.
But when I run same script, the spring server make some run time error "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".
I fumbled a lot and finally find out it occurred only when I accessed & run shell with intellij ssh terminal. I tried with powershell and it worked.

How this problem occurred?? I thought ssh are all the same - intellij embeded or powershell.
I'm fine with my project but I can't understand why.

I tested changing the ssh terminal options of intellij - shell intergration and run commands using IDE, but there is no difference.
intellj version : 2021.3.3

Comment: Hello! Is it possible to check if the issue persists in the latest available IntelliJ IDEA release, 2023.2.3? The version you use is quite old, and the problem could have already been fixed now.

Comment: I stopped my subscription and using fallback version... I'll try in community version soon

Comment: 2023.2.5 community version, worked totally fine.